# Infinite Conducting Planes

Tags: electrostatics, method-of-images

I was reading about the method of image charges, where they've (Irodov) mentioned an "infinite conducting plane". Is this just like an infinite sheet, or does it cover one half of the space?
The reason I'm confused is because its also given that the electric field of the fictitious charge is absent in the half-space it occupies, which points to the latter case. But in one of the questions from Irodov, the answer matched when I solved it assuming the former.
Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Post the question

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the method of images, an infinite conducting plane would behave in the same way as a conducting half-space. There is no sure way to say which one is meant in the book, since there is no standard language in this respect - it varies from a book to another.